# WordPress's database blue-green deployment on Azure

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure, blue-green-deployment

We have a WordPress's application on the Azure's WebApp.

We have two environments there - DEV and Prod. Prod have a Staging swap-slot.

DEV and PROD, obviously, use different MySQL database (we using MySQL In App now, but the same question related to ClearDB/MySQL setup).

So, question is - how to do Blue-green deployment? What to do with databases?

We have Travis configured to deploy code to different environments. But - Prod's database will be updated during its usage be visitors, and DEV will be updated with developers (and, sure - will not have visitor's changes from Prod).

Are there any solutions/practises to realize that?

P.S. And there is one more issue. "MySQL In App (preview)" does not allow to have separated database for WebApp and its Stage (swap-slot). This creates an additional headache for us.

Comment: Same thing I am trying to implement on azure now. Facing the exact situation. @setevoy please suggest, how you are dealing with this.

Comment: @WpTricks24 Hi. Unfortunately - found nothing... One way to do such a deploy I found - using dbForge Studio, although it's manual and painful process. It's not a production solution, but at least - it works. I made a blog post (in russian) describing that process - maybe you can find some examples [there](https://rtfm.co.ua/wordpress-blue-green-deploj-i-sliyanie-baz-mysql-s-pomoshhyu-dbforge-studio/).